# creating db conn file with multiple db info

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I have 4 different databases with 4 different usernames and passwords.  I would like to put all the connection information into one file:  db_conn.php.

db_conn.php

```
<?php

$dbname1 = "courses_classes";
     $web_name ='wart.wmysql.com';
     $web_user = "admin";
     $web_pass="administrator";

$dbname2 ="courses_supplies";
     $web_name ='wart.wmysql.com';
     $web_user = "maint";
     $web_pass="maintenance";
     
$dbname3 = "courses_instructor":
     $web_name ='wart.wmysql.com';
     $web_user = "teacher";
     $web_pass="instructor";

$dbname4 = "webmaster";
     $web_name ='wart.wmysql.com';
     $web_user = "admin";
     $web_pass="webAdmin";
     
?>
```

On different pages this is the code I would like to use if possible:

```
//============================================================ database connection
require('../cgi-bin/db_conn.php');

$dbname = "dbname1";
$table_name = "members";

// Create connection
$conn= new mysqli($web_name,$web_user ,$web_pass,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn-> connect_errno) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn-> connect_error;
     exit();
} 
//else { echo "connected"; }
// ============================================================= end db connection
```

Comment: I don't see how you expect this to work when you use the same variable names, thus overwriting name, user and pass. Maybe organize all this info into an array?

Comment: Do you really need 4 databases, should they all be in the same database and the user name defines access to specific tables/data?

Comment: Yes 4 db are needed because they contain different info.  There is no common field between them, thus they do not relate to each other.

As for the comment on "how you expect this to work"  First off that is condescending and inappropriate.  Second this is a problem needing assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Made one small change by not leaving conn null.  This is the way it now looks

**connect page**

```
$db = [
        'admin' => [
             'db_conn' => 'schoolnet.qwertymysql.com',
             'db_user'  => 'user',
             'db_pass'  => 'pass',
             'db_name' => 'school_comm',
             ],
];
```

**web page**

```
    $selectedConn = 'Content';
    $conn= new mysqli($db[$selectedConn]['db_conn'],
                      $db[$selectedConn]['db_user'] ,
                      $db[$selectedConn]['db_pass'],
                      $db[$selectedConn]['db_name']
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to store your different credentials in an associated array. For example:

```
     $db = [
        'classses' => [
            'db_name' => 'courses_classes',
            'db_user' => 'user',
            'db_pass' => 'pass',
            'conn'    => null,
        ],
        ....
        'supplies' =>..

    ];
```

Then for the connection initiation, you could 'select' the credentials you need based on the key in the array. Example:

```
    $selectedConn = 'classes';
    
    $conn= new mysqli($selectedConn,$db[$selectedConn]['db_user'] ,$db[$selectedConn]['db_pass'],$db[$selectedConn]['db_name']);

    // OR store your connection in the array as well for future reference

    $db[$selectedConn]['conn'] = new mysqli($selectedConn,$db[$selectedConn]['db_user'] ,$db[$selectedConn]['db_pass'],$db[$selectedConn]['db_name']);
```

Comment: This is a great answer and I have employed it.  Thanks, I knew that there was a great way to do this.

Comment: This same process can be used with PDO connections.